# Olive oil versus sunflower oil

Tags: nutrition, cooking, oil

I wondered what was the best for the health.

In general but also, I noticed that my sunflower oil indicates on its bottle that it shouldn't be cooked over 175 C°, what happens if we do (by mistake for instance)?

**Bonus question:** I picked those two oils because this is the only ones I really know about, is there other good alternatives?

**Related question:** [Olive oil versus sunflower oil](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/934/264) (on sustainability.stackexchange.com)

Comment: check this answer: http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/711/can-consuming-food-that-was-cooked-with-olive-oil-have-a-negative-impact-on-heal/993#993

Answer (score 3):

Actually, sunflower oil is very high in omega 6 and poor in omega 3 which isn't a good thing considering that the body needs a good balance between omega 6 and omega 3 to be healthy, and most modern food is way too high in omega 6.

In my opinion there aren't good oils and bad oils, it's all a matter of balance. I personally use olive oil for hot dishes, and colza oil for salads and stuff... most of the time. But you still can try and pick most of the oils if you feel curious (I think that palm oil is the only vegetable oil which isn't good for health even if used just a little).

Sources

- [How to Optimize Your Omega-6 to Omega-3 Ratio](http://authoritynutrition.com/optimize-omega-6-omega-3-ratio/)
- [The Shocking Truth About Sunflower Oil](http://health.usnews.com/health-news/blogs/eat-run/2014/01/03/the-shocking-truth-about-sunflower-oil)

Comment: Welcome to Health SE! This post has the makings of a very good answer, but here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good, reliable sources, check out [this post](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112). If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out [this meta post](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283). Thanks :)

Comment: Done, and will do next times :)